# Click on buttons falters and skips in safari on ipad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I've got follow code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.value = '';

  $scope.keyList = [{
    id: 1,
    name: '1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: '2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: '3'
  }];

  $scope.modifyValue = function(item) {
    $scope.value = $scope.value + item.name;
  }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.keys {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.key {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.key:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div class="keys">
    <div class="key" ng-repeat="item in keyList" ng-click="modifyValue(item)">{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
  <input ng-model="value">
  <button ng-click="value = ''">Clear</button>
</div>
```

This works fine on desktop (IE, firefox and chrome), samsung tab (in chrome) and also on an ipad (in safari). The only problem I have with this solution is the performance on the ipad (in safari). When I click fast on desktop or samsung tab, it concats my value fast and the click also is fast. But when I touch fast on some of the three numbers on my ipad in safari, it falters and skips some numbers. Example: When I click fast 1-2-3, it falters and skips the 2 and so in the input its only 13 in case of 123. I have no idea how to fix it...I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: What happens in safari on OSX? I wonder if iPad had a touch timeout in safari?

Comment: Hi @DanielShillcock I don't know, we just develop our web application for windows desktop (all browsers), samsung tab (chrome) and iPad (safari). We don't have an OSX in house... But is it possible that this problem is because of the fastclick? Cheers..

Comment: @DanielShillcock I solved it with fastclick: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/blob/master/bower.json

Comment: SOLUTION: https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/blob/master/bower.json